# Get info from drawn button linked to a script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to get info from a drawn button? I mean, imagine you've drawn a button with text: "Calculate A"; and button with text: "Calculate B". In both cases you've linked the function calculate() in a script. Would it be possible to get something like a parameter from the button?

```
calculate(button){
    if (button = A){
        calculation(A);
    } if (button = B){
        calculation(B);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can try [to get the active range and check which image is in there](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#getAnchorCell())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a comparison. `button = A` It's an assignment.

Also you didn't define the function properly.

```
function calculate(button){
    if (button == A){
        calculation(A);//This could be another function call
    } if (button == B){
        calculation(B);
    }
}
```

Also note that this function doesn't return anything.

[Functions Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Comment: Thank you Cooper.

Yes, I haven't defined well the function and the comparisons. However, I'm asking if it's possible to identify from which button the function has been fired (drawn buttons).

Comment: No. It's not possible.

Comment: And there is a way to create this buttons from the script therefore have its ids?

Comment: You can create buttons in a dialog or a sidebar.  Dialogs and Sidebars run clientside and so they are constructed with html and javascript.  You can make calls to Google Apps Script from JavaScript  via [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).